# Bringing sql-server query results into a dataFrame in R

Tags: sql-server, r, datetime, timestamp

Assuming I have a working connection and that I am able to pull in whole tables from SQL-server into R without problems.  My issue is I am trying to bring in the results of a query into R after merging the date and time columns in sql into a one datetime column in R plus two other columns
I have dDate, tTime, price, Qty.  In my database.
I want to bring in the data into an R dataframe in three R fields with a timeDate field for the time stamp then Price and Quantity.

I tried this code but it didn't work, conn is my open connection:

```
 sqlFetch(conn,"SELECT Convert(datetime,dDate + ' ' + tTime,20) as tranTime, Price, Qty From myTable order by dDate, tTime")
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try using `sqlQuery` instead of `sqlFetch`

Comment: What does didn't work mean ?

Comment: the error is "table not found on channel"

Comment: I try sqlQuery instead of sqlFetch nothing happens no errors and no results the query just gets dropped without results.

Comment: I don't think RODBC can handle temporary tables btw. Try to simplify your code.

Answer (score 0):

Pull   data from SQL in XML format by adding  FOR XML AUTO   to end of your sql reuest:

```
 SELECT Convert(datetime,dDate + ' ' + tTime,20) as tranTime, Price, Qty
 From myTable order by dDate, tTime
 FOR XML AUTO
```

result will be like this

```
<myTable Trantime="10" Price="17"  Qty="34" />
```

Use XML package for R (will give all options to extract data )

```
library(XML)
file <- xmlParse(XMLDATA )
```

Comment: this is a round about way to doing it maybe, thanks for sharing